# Does an attack redirected to an invisible target have disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility, advantage-and-disadvantage

An interesting combo came up in gameplay: An invisible party member chose to defend another party member using their non-spell, non-attack reaction (arrow catching shield.)

In the description for the **[*invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility)** spell (PH pg. 254), it says:

> The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell.

In the description for the **[*arrow-catching shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/arrow-catching-shield)**, it says

> In addition, whenever an attacker makes a ranged attack against a
>   target within 5 feet of you, you can use your reaction to become the
>   target of the attack instead.

According to the rules of the **[invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible)** condition (PHB, pg. 291):

> Attack rolls against you have disadvantage.

Should the attack now be with disadvantage, even though it's already been made?

The central question is **Does redirecting an attack to a different target cause the attack to be made under the rules for the conditions affecting the new target?**

Comment: How about I delete and re-ask?

Comment: There's no need to delete it. Just edit one of the two questions out of this post and ask it separately. Then this one can be reopened, and the other question can be answered properly as well.

Comment: Thanks. Reworded so specifically address the condition aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an attack, nor casting a spell, so invisibility does not end.

My reading of the shield is that you have to declare that you direct the arrow at yourself before the arrow has hit or missed the target. If the GM has already rolled for the attack and you declare that you want to redirect the arrow at yourself, that attack roll becomes invalid and the GM makes a new attack roll with disadvantage against you.

Comment: I'm giving the correct answer to you because you also address the "outside the rules aspect."
Out DM tends to announce "The monster hits the mage for..." And then we do our reactions and the re-roll aspect seems the more... real-world gameplay fair.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

When the attack is declared you can choose to make yourself the target of it. If you do you remain invisible (because you have not attacked or cast a spell) and the attack is made with disadvantage as a result of your invisibility. If you don’t so choose the attack is made against your ally normally.

If you wait until the attack has been rolled you no longer have the option to make yourself the target. The shield is not one of those effects where you get to see the roll before you decide to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to try and train our DM to announce the attack first before he declares a hit, just so I can have a better chance to use this item,

Answer (score 0):

## No for both

Invisibility, from the spell of the same name, only ends when you make an attack or cast a spell as you stated.

Being invisible wouldn't cause disadvantage if you redirect the attack since the attack roll was made against your ally, not you.

Comment: FYI, the question has been updated to present just one question.